# Cordova Camera Locked on Portrait only

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ipad hybrid application (ionic framework) that uses Cordova Camera, I manage to launch the camera and return a picture, but the issue is that the camera is always lock with portrait mode only no matter how the iPad is being rotate, below are my codes

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(data){

}, function(error){

}, {
    quality : 75, 
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 512,
    targetHeight: 384,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
});
```

I have also set "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" under the Xcode project

I have also set portrait only under config.xml for the ionic project, below are the codes,

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Do hope that someone can help me troubleshoot on this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, is the device orientation lock?

Comment: except camera is it working landscape mode?

Comment: Hi @user1872384 , the device is not orientation lock, I did try to lock it with landscape mode, but the camera is still in portrait mode.

Comment: Hi @DivyeshSavaliya ,the normal iOS Camera with working fine with landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: What is the exact build version of your IBM MobileFirst platform ? If you run this exact code in a pure Cordova application, does it work both in landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: What iPad are you using to test?

Comment: First confirm this does not happen in a pure cordova app. If it doesn't happen with pure cordova but happens only with mobilefirst - first upgrade to the latest iFix, and if that fails too - open a PMR.